# I want to set a daily reminder (local notification) and also a reminder 10 seconds after the user enters a button

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently, my code only sends a reminder 86400 seconds (one day) after the user enters the button but does not repeat, even though I changed the `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger's` repeat property to `"true"`.

Here is my code:

```
 let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Facts, tips, and tricks to help you quit:"
        content.body = reminders.randomElement()!
        content.sound = .default
        content.userInfo = ["value": "Data with local notification"]

        let fireDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date().addingTimeInterval(86400))

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: fireDate, repeats: true)


        // UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 20, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error = \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error local notification")")
            }
        }
```

It is inside of an `IBAction`. I would like it to repeat every day once and also have one message 10 seconds after the user clicks the button.

How would this be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: its fires every 24 hours :
myNotificationRequest.trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60*60*24, repeats: true)

Comment: My code doesn't repeat at all. Are you saying I should add that line of code you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it: Convert current date (when you tap on a button) into date components and schedule a notification for that particular time every day.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Facts, tips, and tricks to help you quit:"
content.body = reminders.randomElement()!
content.sound = .default
content.userInfo = ["value": "Data with local notification"]

let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let second = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = hour
dateComponents.minute = minute
dateComponents.second = second
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
center.add(request)
```

Comment: So if I want the notification to be sent at 2 p.m. I set dateComponents.hour to 14, and the other two to zero? Thanks btw!

Comment: You could just omit the assignment of hours and minutes: var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.hour = hour
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)